# Loader before website fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I have this sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<!-- This next would probably be in your main CSS file, but shown
     inline here just for purposes of the example
-->
<style type="text/css">
body {
    /* Hide it for nifty fade-in effect */
    display: none;
}
</style>
<!-- Fallback for non-JavaScript people -->
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    /* Re-displays it by overriding the above */
    display: block;
}
</style>
</noscript>
</head>
<body>
...content...
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
// This version runs the function *immediately*
(function($) {

$(window).load(function() {
$(document.body).fadeIn(1000);
});

})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the webpage waits till it's loaded and then fades in. But in some cases, some users might have a slow internet and might be confused by the website taking a while to load. I've tried to look for jQuery or other preloaders but none seem to work with my code. How could I add a small, centered loading gif to this code to let the users know the webpage is indeed loading?

Also, this is related to the same website so I didn't want to post another question. My background img changes randomly every time the page is reloaded. This is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var upperLimit = 13;

var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * upperLimit) + 1);    


 $("#banner").css("background-image","url('css/images/overlay.png'), url('images/" + randomNum + ".jpg')")


 });
 </script>
```

It works great. Now, the only little thing I wondered was, how could I make that background img fade in? I can't seem to make it work by adding .fadeIn(1000); to the code.

```
$("#banner").css("background-image","url('css/images/overlay.png'), url('images/" + randomNum + ".jpg')").fadeIn(1000);
```

How can I make it fade in so it looks a little bit neater?

Answer (score 0):

You can define some HTML for the loader element, then fade it out when you fade in the page.

However currently you're hiding/fading the body of the page. You would need to wrap all the content you want to postpone displaying in another element as a sibling to your loader.

For example:

```
<body>
  <div id="loader"><img src="loading-image.png"></div>
  <div id="page-content">
    <!-- content here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Then you change your CSS and JS to refer to `#page-content` instead of `body`.

If you're fading the page in, why doesn't it also fade the banner image? I think you can wrap this in the same mechanic.

Comment: Apparently it will fade in but the banner might appear a couple secs later without fading in! And I don't understand why

Comment: It would be useful if you could reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can more accurately see what you mean.